# transfer files in a tcp threaded server C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Hi everyone i have a little problem, i supposed to transfer a file from a server( a tcp server with threads to a client). The problems appers at the end of transmision the file is recived by client but it stucks and I can't longer communicate with it.

## This is the server

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

//Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(2025);

//Bind
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
//print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

//Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 5);

//Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    int enable = 1;

//Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    pthread_t thread_id;

    while ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc,
                                 (struct sockaddr *) &client,
                                 (socklen_t*) &c)))
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        if (setsockopt(client_sock,
                       SOL_SOCKET,
                       SO_REUSEADDR,
                       &enable,
                       sizeof(int)) < 0)
            error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
        if (pthread_create(&thread_id,
                           NULL,
                           connection_handler,
                           (void*) &client_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

//Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    printf("Enter in handler");
//Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*) socket_desc;
    send_problemo(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

## This is the sending function where I think is the real problem

```
int send_problemo(int *sock)
{
    ssize_t read_return;
    char *file_path = "Problems/1.txt";
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    int filefd;
    filefd = open(file_path, O_RDONLY);
    char end[2] = "1";
    if (filefd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        read_return = read(filefd, buffer, BUFSIZ);
        if (read_return == 0)
        {
            printf("este 0 \n");
            break;
        }
        if (read_return == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (write(sock, buffer, read_return) == -1)
        {
            perror("write");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
// close(sock);
    close(filefd);
}
```

## The client is connecting normally and receives the file in this function

```
int recive_problemo(int *sockfd)
{
    char *file_path = "path.c";
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    ssize_t read_return;
    int filefd;
    filefd = open(file_path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (filefd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    do
    {
        read_return = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZ);
        if (read_return == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (write(filefd, buffer, read_return) == -1)
        {
            perror("write");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while (read_return > 0);
    close(filefd);
}
```

I kind of managed how to solve this. If i shutdown(SHUT_WR) from server the client isnt stuck anymore, but i want to communicate with it further.
Also with the same function if i transfer from client to server, it works perfectly, so can anyone help me please?

Comment: This code is in dire need of proper indentation.

Comment: Indentation is for the weak. Real men like the pain.

Comment: There is exactly no point in `setsockopt(client_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int))`. The client socket is already bound and is in no need of this option.

Comment: 'pthread_join...'  why?

Comment: '(void*) &client_sock' - bad.  Two 'simultaneous' accepted connections could mutate 'client_sock' before the intended thread reads it:(

Comment: '// close(sock);'  why did you comment out the socket close?

Comment: Why not look at any of the many nice protocols for sending files over TCP such as HTTP or FTP to see how they do it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
do
{
    read_return = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZ);
    // error handling
    // file write
} while (read_return > 0);
```

Will keep looping until the socket closes or there's an error. It has no way to tell if a file has finished.

Common solutions are to close the socket (but you don't want that) and establish a communication protocol so that you know when the file is done and can exit the loop.

To keep things very simple, I recommend sending the length of the file before sending the file. The loop now looks something like:

```
uint64_t file_len;
read_return = recv(sockfd, &file_len, sizeof(file_len), MSG_WAITALL);
if (read_return == sizeof(file_len))
{
    // Strongly consider handling the endian of file_len here
    while (file_len)
    {
        size_t readmax = std::min(file_len, BUFSIZ);
        read_return = read(sockfd, buffer, readmax); 
        if (read_return > 0)
        {
            if (write(filefd, buffer, read_return) == -1)
            {
                perror("write");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            file_len -= read_return;
        }
        else
        {
             // handle error
             // exit loop if not recoverable
        }
    }
}
```

The server end picks up the responsibility of getting and sending the length of the file. I won't get into that because there are too many different ways to get the length of a file. Pick your favourite.

[Documentation on `recv` and `MSG_WAITALL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html).

Comment: Well it should be a `while` loop, not a `do/while` loop, otherwise you have to test the termination condition again inside the loop to prevent writing or processing junk. For example if there is an error your code will increment `file_len` pointlessly.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Well, actually I can, but I'm not stupid enough to. I was trying to stick close to what Asker started with and then kludged with a comment, when I should have started fresh. Will patch in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you sir, you made my day , I've lost a couple of hours for this problem, but can you tell me please why my soulution is working to transfer from client to server but it is stucking otherwise? Thank you so much again. @user4581301

Comment: I don't know. If you are using the same code both ways it should have failed both ways. Something is different, but I don't know what.

Comment: @user4581301 I was just curious, really the code is the same copy-paste, the problem appears in threads/forks, if i remove them there is no problem sending from server to client.

Comment: @MateiMădălin get rid of the pthread_join.  It is a call of death.

Comment: You've removed the `do/while` but the problem I mentioned remains.

Comment: @EJP not if the error handling exits the loop out of the loop. Will make this more clear.